# Need help solving a javascript issue with a button being clicked that is not being clicked

Tags: javascript, button, innerhtml, divider

Ok, so I have a web interface I'm designing that I'm having a problem with.  It's an interface to configure remotes to control functions of an ESP32.  The code on the ESP32 is definitely not the problem here, it's something in the javascript that I am fairly new to for sure.  Here's the process...  The web interface has kind of a tab structure (menu at top, dividers for each "tab" that are hidden or shown depending on which menu item you click)  So, there's a remote configuration tab (). When the page is loaded, the script sends a websocket command to the controller requesting the remote configuration.  The controller then sends back data which my javascript takes and puts into the innerhtml of the divider containing an html table list of the remotes paired with the device and edit/delete buttons for each one as well as a back button.

Delete buttons are currently not implemented as I want to get everything else working before deleting anything.

The edit button passes a command to the controller with then loads a new table containing some editable data and a list of the buttons the remote has into the innerhtml of the divider.

This list of buttons also has edit and delete functions which are pretty similar to the above as well as a back button.

The back button on the "edit button" function is what is giving me a hard time.  Basically, the back button runs the same function as the edit remote function reloading the remote configuration and list of buttons into the innerhtml.

Here's the real problem...

I click the edit on a remote, it loads the remote config and list of buttons.  I click the edit on a button, it loads the button configuration.  I click back, and....

script sends command to edit remote
then...
script sends command to edit button

It should not be sending the edit button command.

I've included a link below to reproduce this issue without you having the controller itself.  I've also added alert messages to make it clear what is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Link to JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/kb1sph/37epovwg/

```html
My code is too big for this post, but to add a jsfiddle link I need a code snippet...so here's a dummy code snippet.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). As it is now, there is more text than most of us care to read

Comment: @mplungjan As I am new to this, can you clarify why I should get the elements by the container id as opposed to class name?  As it is now, for css formatting, the buttons are both in one divider, but I could put each in their own.  As all of the buttons have the same class name (remedit for all remotes, remdel for all remotes), but the ID is set to the ID of the remote (edit and del buttons have same id) that is why I added the events by class name.  I could change it so that the remote ids are in a data- property as well.  This does look like it would clean up the code to have less though.

Comment: @mplungjan My post has been edited to be not quite as long and include a JSFiddle link to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I should clarify what I was asking a little more. While it does look like it would clean up the code a bit, is there any other particular reason, or advantage to add click events based on the container ID vs adding them to the buttons by class? I'm only asking to learn more if I can.

Comment: As far as the fontawesome, I came across that once before, but was under the impression that the device loading the page would need internet access to use it. The device I am designing will sometimes be in a remote or mobile location that does not have internet access. It will simply be connected to from a phone or tablet to configure the remotes. I will look into it more and see if it can be used offline and the space required for files. File size can be a limitation as the portion of flash on the device for the file system is smaller than the amount of space available for the program itself.

Comment: Hmmm, while I don't understand why the script was acting as if the "edit button" button was clicked again when I try to go back, using your method does two things. First, it cleans up the code. Second, it means I only have to add the click event once on page loading vs adding it to each button.  And, for some reason this solved the issue of the button mysteriously being clicked when it wasn't. If you could put your code into an answer instead of comment, I will accept it as the solution if you'd like.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: New problem (minor) with doing it by the container and getting the target.  It seems when I click on the SVG, it doesn't call the edit function.  If I click in the space around it, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delegate (you need to target the button itself) you do not need to loop over the buttons.

Added benefit, which solves one of your issues: If you add the buttons later, the container will still handle the event

The other issue was that you likely added eventHandlers more than once to the same buttons

```js
const remotegrid = document.getElementById('remotegrid');
remotegrid.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // you can click anywhere on the buttom
  if      (tgt.matches(".remedit")) editrem(tgt);
  else if (tgt.matches(".btnedit")) editbtn(tgt);
  else if (tgt.matches(".remdel"))  delrem(tgt);
  else if (tgt.matches(".btndel"))  delbtn(tgt);
});
```

To shorten your code, you can load fontawesome onto the device and use code like `<i class="fal fa-pencil"></i>` instead of the SVG

or even smaller:

```
 <button class='btnedit' title='Edit Button'>✎</button>
 <button class='btndel' title='Delete Button'></button>
```

How about changing this

```
function ChangeTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "grid";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

to this much more readable code. Also it uses native classlist manipulation instead of an error prone replace with commas and spaces

```
const ChangeTab = (evt, tabName) => {
  const currenttab = evt.currentTarget;
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent")
    .forEach(content => content.style.display = "none");
  document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks")
    .forEach(tablink => tablink.classList.toggle("active",tablink === currenttab));
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "grid";
};
```

Here is another improved event handler

```
remotegrid.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("[name=remoteenabled]")) return; 
  SendCmd(`<RemoteEnabled MAC="${tgt.id}" Enabled="${tgt.value}"/>`);
});
```

I have added many changes to https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vn6gh2jx/

I may have broken some functionality, but it does not error

To shorten it even more, look into [template elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: Thank you! This really helped. I have no idea why it was acting like two buttons were clicked. Even if I was adding event listeners multiple times, it would have been the right events for the right buttons and not acting as if two buttons were clicked. Using your suggestions and delegating vs looping over buttons solved the issue. I'm not sure what functionality you may have broken, but with all the changes implemented, everything seems to work fine. I even made further modifications to other code that wasn't listed based on your suggestions with success. I really appreciate the help!